# .NET Change number of times to loop whilst inside loop

Tags: vb.net

Am investigating how to modify a loops end value whilst inside the loop.  This is .NET2 code (and am using VB).  I understand this is not ideal, however can it be done?

```
'inital value is 31
Dim currentNumberOfRowsInDataTable As Int32 = dataTable.Rows.Count - 1

For i As Integer = 0 To currentNumberOfRowsInDataTable
    Try
        If (dataTable.Rows(i)("DataItemSection") = "Platforms") Then
            Dim newRow As DataRow = rearrangedDataTable.NewRow()

            'do stuff

            dataTable.Rows.RemoveAt(i)
            'decrement to 30, however this has no influence on the loop
            currentNumberOfRowsInDataTable -= 1
        End If
    Catch
        'problem is that loop always goes to 31, whereas I want it to go to 30
        'so need to swallow the exception here
    End Try
Next
```

EDIT - there was C# code here, however took it out as it didn't produce the same behaviour.

Comment: VB's [`For...Next` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z06z1kb.aspx): "Changing the value of *start*, *end*, or *step* doesn't affect the iteration values that were determined when the loop was first entered."

Comment: I hadn't tried the C#.. used http://converter.telerik.com/ to try and make question clearer.  My bad.

Comment: Good suggestion DTU - have done that.

Comment: Also, is it your intention to skip checking the new row that is now at position `i` following your `RemoveAt`? If not, I'd definitely go with @Dennis_E's suggestion to iterate backwards rather than forwards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using `while loop` suit your requirement

VB code:

```
'inital value is 31
Dim currentNumberOfRowsInDataTable As Int32 = dataTable.Rows.Count - 1
Dim i As Integer = 0

While i <= currentNumberOfRowsInDataTable 
    Try
        If (dataTable.Rows(i)("DataItemSection") = "Platforms") Then
            Dim newRow As DataRow = rearrangedDataTable.NewRow()

            'do stuff

            dataTable.Rows.RemoveAt(i)
            'decrement to 30, however this has no influence on the loop
            currentNumberOfRowsInDataTable -= 1
        Else  
            i += 1
        End If
    Catch
        'problem is that loop always goes to 31, whereas I want it to go to 30
        'so need to swallow the exception here
    End Try
End While
```

**EDIT**
I removed C# code because you're using VB.NET and look like you don't need a C# conversion. As @Damien_The_Unbeliever said, if we remove the a row at `i`, then the next row will take place of the removed row, therefore my previous code will lead to missing checking on the next row when a current row at `i` is deleted. In order to avoid that, put the increment of `i` into an `else` block so that `i` will only increase if no row was deleted. I updated my code above

Comment: As indicated in a comment on the question, this does mean that the *new* row that now occupies position `i` will not be checked. If that's not the desired behaviour, the `i+=1` should be in an `Else`

Comment: I see, I was focused on convert his `for loop` to `while loop` and forget to notice the logic flow, thank for your remind @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Answer (score 6):

If you're removing something from a List while looping through it, you should start at the end. C#:

```
for (int i = currentNumberOfRowsInDataTable - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
  //the rest here
}
```

Quote:

```
//decrement to 30, however this has no influence on the loop
currentNumberOfRowsInDataTable -= 1;
```

End quote

This WILL influence the loop.
However, if you start at the end the whole problem will go away.